# Keep getting <style> for css file and not actual file - trying to use Gulp sourcemaps

Tags: magento2, css, less

So I have updated the default_head_blocks.xml file with my css file like so and the theme loads the CSS.

```
<css src="css/master.css" />
```

This is my gulpfile.

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
const livereload = require("gulp-livereload");
const less = require("gulp-less");
const wait = require("gulp-wait");
const sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

gulp.task("less", function() {
  return gulp
    .src([
      "./app/design/frontend/Sm/market/web/css/master.less",
      "./app/design/frontend/Sm/market/web/css/ytextend.less",
      "./app/design/frontend/Sm/market/web/css/yttheme.less"
    ])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe( sourcemaps.write() )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./pub/static/frontend/Sm/market/en_GB/css"))
    .pipe(wait(2000))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
// Watch Files For Changes and livereload
gulp.task("watch", function() {
  livereload.listen();
  // gulp.watch("./app/design/frontend/Sm/market/web/css/*.less", ["less"]);
  gulp.watch("./app/design/frontend/Sm/market/web/css/**/*.less", ["less"]);
  // gulp.watch("./pub/static/frontend/Sm/market/en_GB/css/market.css", ["reload"]);
});

gulp.task("default", ["less", "watch"]);
```

However, I can't seem to get sourcemaps working correctly.

This is what shows on the dev tools for Chrome. When it should be showing the .less file or at least master.css - When I click that it does take me to the href for the stylesheet in pub/static folder. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this problem. Had to write the sourcesmaps to a folder - ./maps - inline wasn't working. Also, ensure there are no errors in your LESS files.

```
gulp.task("less", function() {
  return gulp
    .src([
      "./app/design/frontend/Sm/market/web/css/master.less",
      "./app/design/frontend/Sm/market/web/css/ytextend.less",
      "./app/design/frontend/Sm/market/web/css/yttheme.less"
    ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe( sourcemaps.write('./maps') )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./pub/static/frontend/Sm/market/en_GB/css"))
    .pipe(wait(2000))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```